# Installying packages in Spyder such as geopandas - "No module named XXXXXXX"

Tags: python, python-import, conda, spyder

I am running Spyder 4.0.1 that I installed on Windows through the Anaconda distribution.

Using Conda, I installed the package Geopandas, by using the following prompt

```
conda install geopandas
```

It seemed to work.

However, if I open Spyder, and use the command

```
import geopandas as gpd
```

I get the message

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'
```

I'm not sure what the error is here as I think geopandas has indeed been installed. Any help would be gratefull received.

Comment: Are you executing the program with the correct Python installation?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure - I suspect that Spyder is linked to a different version of python than anaconda. How can I check and change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geopandas` comes with Anaconda's distribution, but it's only availible if you configure your Spider to use the `conda environment`.

Please check the [Spyder GitHub's repository](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder) for more specific information.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this is it - I can see my environments are different and I have to ensure they're the same somehow. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing it via Anaconda's PowerShell prompt (pip install geopandas)?

Comment: I did just try but I got an error (sorry, I don't know how to edit my reply better)   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Gebruiker\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\GEBRUI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2g0dc_cz\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"';